# asp.net mvc - show content from string with html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, rendering

in my Model I have a string property Feeds with value like that:

```
<img src="/Images/Company/twitter.png" style="border:0; vertical-align:text-bottom;"/>
&nbsp;
<b>
    9/29/2010 1:01:33 PM
</b>
<br/>
How to get started building rich #VS2010 #VSPackage based extensions - 
<a href="http://bit.ly/a8ksc1" target="_NEW">
    http://bit.ly/a8ksc1
</a>
<br/>&nbsp;<br/>
<img src="/Images/Company/twitter.png" style="border:0; vertical-align:text-bottom;"/>
&nbsp;
<b>    
    9/3/2010 9:51:26 AM
</b>
<br/>
Windows Phone 7 – Released To Manufacturing 
<a href="http://bit.ly/a7HHvw" target="_NEW">
    http://bit.ly/a7HHvw
</a>
<br/>&nbsp;<br/><br/>
<img src="/Images/Company//rss.png" style="border:0; vertical-align:text-bottom;"/>
&nbsp;RSS feed to busy :-(
<br/>
```

How can I show it like html in my view??
I can get it out in textArea, but i want to just to show it like html.

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(obj => obj.Feeds, 60, 40, null) %>
```

Comment: Okay, maybe I don't understand the problem, but can't you just print it? <%= Model.Feeds %>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<%= Model.Feeds %>

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<%=Html.Encode(Model.Feeds)%>
```

this will encode ur tags to html equivalent codes and they will not be interpreted when rendering them on the web page.